# getting error while removing duplicates from csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**My csv file is on this link:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pac9-YLAtc7iaN0qEuiBOpYYf9ZPDDaL/view?usp=sharing

I want to remove the duplicate from the csv by checking length of **genres** against each artist ID. If an artist have 2 records in csv (e.g., ed sheeran's id **6eUKZXaKkcviH0Ku9w2n3V** have 2 records one record have 1 genres while row#5 have 5 genres so i want to keep the row which has largest genres length)

I'm using this script for now:

```
import pandas
import ast


df = pandas.read_csv('39K.csv', encoding='latin-1')

df['lst_len'] = df['genres'].map(lambda x: len(ast.literal_eval(str(x))))
print(df['lst_len'][0])

df = df.sort_values('lst_len', ascending=False)

# Drop duplicates, preserving first (longest) list by ID
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID')


# Remove extra column that we introduced, write to file
df = df.drop('lst_len', axis=1)
df.to_csv('clean_39K.csv', index=False)
```

but this script works for 500 record (may be i have illusion that size of records matters),

but when I run this script for my largest file **39K.csv** I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
******* error in line 5, in <module>....
    df['lst_len'] = df['genres'].map(lambda x: len(list(x)))
    df['lst_len'] = df['genres'].map(lambda x: len(list(x)))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Please point me where i am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bad data at (at least) line 16553 of your input csv file:

```
52lUXCmpmAIVsgNd1uADOy,Moosh & Twist,NULL
```

`pandas` interprets `NULL` as `nan` when it reads the file, which is of type `float` and is not iterable. There are a few other `NULL` entries in there too, so you could either manually remove or fix them (preferred), or handle this case in your code.

For example, if you actually want to pretend that `NULL` should be interpreted as an empty list, you can preprocess the data like this (just after reading the csv):

```
df.loc[df['genres'].isnull(),['genres']] = df.loc[df['genres'].isnull(),'genres'].apply(lambda x: [])
```

Or more elegantly, switch to reading the csv using `na_filter=False`:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('39K.csv', encoding='latin-1', na_filter=False)
```

which will prevent pandas from replacing these values with `nan` in the first place.

Finally, the code doesn't quite do what we ant because it is counting the number of characters in the string representation of the list. The solution is to preprocess the NULL values into strings representing empty lists, then use `ast.literal_eval` to turn all the strings back into lists:

```
import pandas
import ast

    df = pandas.read_csv('39K.csv', encoding='latin-1', na_filter=False)
    df.replace(to_replace="NULL", value="[]", inplace=True)

    for item in df['genres']:

        print(str(item))
        print(ast.literal_eval(item))

    df['lst_len'] = df['genres'].map(lambda x: len(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

Comment: Or maybe worth doing pre-processing with `DataFrame.fillna("0")`  or with empty  across the dataframe.

Comment: @pygo I thought that, but I'm not sure that will work, because `fillna` doesn't accept a list as its argument, and we explicitly want an empty list because we will later be calculating its length. Using `fillna("0")` definitely doesn't work (tested) without further processing.

Comment: Hmm,  how about `df = df.fillna('')`  which will fill na's (e.g. NaN's) with '' ie empty, or alternatively `df.read_csv(path , na_filter=False)` which will default consider  empty fields as empty strings.

Comment: @pygo using `fillna('')` still didn't work, those values still ened up being `nan`. But your idea about `na_filter=False` worked beautifully, thanks, I've edited it into the answer.

Comment: @RobBricheno, awesome !

Comment: it works on whole file. You save my day. Stay safe sir. :)

Comment: I just realised, this is also kind of buggy. You wanted the number of genres, but this is actually giving us the length of the string in the genres column. I was worried that 'NULL'  would get interpreted as length 4, which it does. But it's worse than that: every list is interpreted as a string. Will think how to fix...

Comment: oh for this yeah i checked it too. for empty list it treated it as string and gives length 2 for '[]'

Comment: import ast

df['lst_len'] = df['genres'].map(lambda x: len(ast.literal_eval(str(x)))

Comment: but was giving error, after your answer i tried this and working fine

Comment: @BindassClashers Cool! And yes ast.literal_eval is the solution here, I've added it in to the answer as a final thought.